# How to query the type of a default method?

Tags: haskell, ghc

The GHC extension [DefaultSignatures](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#ghc-flag--XDefaultSignatures) allows to change the type of a default method:

```
class Enum a where
  enum :: [a]
  default enum :: (Generic a, GEnum (Rep a)) => [a]
  enum = map to genum
```

Is it possible to ask the compiler for the type of the default method? What is the syntax to do so? `:t enum` is not enough (since it obviously reports `enum :: Enum a => [a]`).

Comment: Maybe `:i Enum` shows it? I'm unsure, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:info Enum` will do it.

For your example, this will produce the output

```hs
class Enum a where
  enum :: [a]
  default enum :: (Generic a, GEnum (Rep a)) => [a]
        -- Defined at ...
```